# sql query based on string "1,5,3,7" -> keep order in result

Tags: php, mysql

i have a simple php string with some id's.

```
    $string = "10, 5, 10, 3";
```

i want to fetch based on these ids some sql, without loosing the order of the ids saved in the string. i tryed:

```
    SELECT * FROM media WHERE ID IN ($string);
```

but the results are now ordered, and double id's are gone

```
    output array:  3, 5, 10
```

how could i use MYSQL to get the rows like this

```
    row0 : id=>10, 
    row1 : id=>5,
    row2 : id=>10,
    row3 : id=>3
```

is there a way doing this without running a query for every id ?

for a better understanding - here my table structure for table called media. its for saving uploaded images + description + metadata.

```
    id, int
    file, varchar
    description_de, varchar
    description_en, varchar
    size, varchar
    width, int
    height, int
```

and there is a table "projects" where i store just the image id for a project . the structure is complex. nobody need to know here. theres a field "media" where i store the media-ids like this :  "1,5,33,9,10,1" to store TWO things.  first the ORDER of images i wana display. SECOND the image id itself .

i need a query to get the images with basicly all fields from media - in the right ORDER .

Comment: Can you post the actual records from the table and your expected records in the order for the id in search?

Comment: so there is a table "media" with id(int), file(varchar), description(varchar) . so its a table to store images with descriptions...   the $string with some ids is part of a table "project" where i wana save these images in a specified order.   so i expect the query to result me an array of rows what contain the id, file, and description.  i just need to keep the order of the image list ... and if there is double images - i dont wana reduce these ...

Comment: ok i added some more information in my post ... hope it helps

Comment: if you have access to mysql command line client, open it, connect, and execute `select` on your source tables. copy the query and output from there and add it to the question you posted

Comment: And then tell us which of the records you want as expected results

Comment: sorry, dont get why u need that. i think my question is pretty simple - and all my table fields are not nessesary and confusing for the question alone.  what i expect as a result was described in my question. i dont get how this helps :/  for now i use Shoaib Zafar his solution by simply fetch per sql and then resort the result in php.

Answer (score 0):

its better to handle on the php side. Pass the unique ID's to mysql query and shape the data as per your need.

```
$x = [['id'=>10, 'name'=>'a'], ['id'=>3, 'name'=>'b'], ['id'=>5, 'name'=>'c'] ];
$order = [10,3,5,10,3,5];

$result = [];
foreach($order as $k => $v){
  foreach($x as $x_a){
    if($x_a['id'] == $v){ $result[$k] = $x_a; break; }
  } 
}
print_r($result);
```

Comment: oh ok, thats inspiring. you think i should simply run the the query to fetch - and then order it again . i see.

Comment: thanks a lot - it works out of the box, i just had to explode the $string to an $order array.   to bad i dont get the foreach loop at 8 in the morning - coding durring the night :)